# Custom Bash prompt doesn't display correctly in shell mode

Tags: shell, shell-mode

In my `.bashrc` file I've set the `PS1` variable to this to customize my prompt:

```
export PS1='[\D{%Y-%d-%m} \t \u@\h \W]\n$ '
```

[The format strings are explained in the Bash manual.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Controlling-the-Prompt)
  This one gives me a prompt that looks like this (in OS X terminal):

```
[2016-10-06 11:15:16 username@host ~]
$ <command goes here>
```

But when I fire up `M-x shell` it doesn't display right:

```
[\D{-/Users/username/-hostname} \t \u@\h \W]\n$ <command here>
```

What's going on here?  Searching for similar issues I mostly run into cases where people had problems with colorized shell output, but I'm not using that.  And my prompt doesn't really have anything that Emacs shouldn't be able to display.

Environment info:

- GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.21) of 2015-04-10 on builder10-9.porkrind.org
- GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
- `echo $TERM`:

  - In OS X Terminal: `xterm-256color`
  - In Emacs `shell`: `dumb`

`M-x terminal` works fine, but I don't like `M-x terminal`...

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE! Does this issue still occur when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`? If not, please try to [bisect your init file](//meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/a/204/675).

Comment: @ScottWeldon: Good suggestion!  No, it doesn't happen with `-Q`.  I'll try and track it down from there!

Comment: ...and now I feel like a dumbass.  My `custom.el` had `'(shell-file-name "/usr/bin/zsh")`.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: No problem; glad you got it fixed. Feel free to [post that information as an answer](//emacs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by an error in the users init, and is unlikely to be useful to other readers.